# Is there a possibility to hide property

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to hide some variables in wix msi file. The reason for that is that i don't want to allow administrator to change this variable using i.e. Orca.
Is there a possibility to hide property in wix project.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way the property is being used. If it's a constant then you could just set it with some simple custom action code just before you use it. But if it needs to be declared as property in the MSI file you can't hide it.

Comment: And I could create a transform to override it after he sets it.   Simple answer is there's no hiding in MSI.  By design... :)